# Pygame text not rendering

Tags: python, text, pygame, render

Okay, so I am making a multiple choice quiz game with python and pygame. However, I am done with the start screen and trying to make the question screen. I simply can't figure out why the text doesn't render. Here's my code:

```
    enter_pressed = False

    random_question = random.randrange(1, 3)
    question_number = 0

    # Sets the height and width of the screen
    size = [720, 575] 
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size),pygame.FULLSCREEN)

    # The Caption for the display
    pygame.display.set_caption("Quiz")

    # Function that automatically renders text
    def render_text(word, x, y, font, size, color):
        # Itinitialize font
        my_font = pygame.font.SysFont(font, size) 
        # Renders font
        label = my_font.render(word, 1, (color))
        screen.blit(label, (x, y))

    # Loops until the user clicks the close button
    done = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # While loop
    while not done:

        # Leaves the fps at 30
        clock.tick(30)

        for event in pygame.event.get(): # If user did something
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # If user pressed a key
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN: # If user pressed enter
                    # Makes the start screen go away
                    enter_pressed = True
                    # Increments question_number
                    question_number += 1

                    **#This is what won't render!!!
                    render_text("Stud", 200, 200, "Arial", 30, BLACK)**

        # Set the screen background
        screen.fill(BACKGROUND)

        # Removes start screen
        if enter_pressed == False:

            # Where drawing happens
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [285, 237, 150, 100])

            # Renders START
            render_text("START", 287, 260, "Arial", 45, BLACK)

            # Renders Celebrity Car Museum:
            render_text("Quiz", 165, 80, "Cooper std", 50, BLACK)

            # Renders Car Quiz
            render_text("Quiz", 285, 150, "Cooper std", 50, BLACK)

            # Renders Press ENTER to start
            render_text("Press ENTER to start", 282, 350, "Impact", 20, BLACK)

        # Update the screen
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rendering the text and immediately cleaning the screen.

Never draw while processing events, just update the game state, then draw that state. Just like you did with `enter_pressed == False`, you should put an `else` and render your text there.

Comment: Thank you, I Forgot that not only does filling the background set a background, it cleans the screen as well.