# Pygame Text Blit and time.sleep not working

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having a hard time with `pygame` blitting text onto the screen. Right now before quitting I just want to have a message show up for 2 seconds, then have the game quit. To do this I use `time.sleep(2)`. However, and I believe most other people don't have this issue from questions I've looked up on Stackoverflow, the text just doesn't show up until what seems to be the last moment before the window closes. Rather, the screen remains white after pressing the close button. My code is below. Please note that this is **not** a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834864/pygame-text-not-rendering).

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

display_width = 800
display_height  = 600
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

FPS = 30

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

x = False
while not x:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            x = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white)    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

screen_text = font.render('Test', True, red)
gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(2)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Does it work without the time.sleep?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 it just quits immediately then so I'm not really sure if the time.sleep is the issue but it seems to be calling the `update()` after the time.sleep suggesting something strangely asynchronous... pretty confused.

Comment: This actually seems like a pretty tough problem! Interestingly, your code "works" on my computer in Windows 10 and python 2/3. However, `time.sleep(n)` is not optimal, since the pygame window will freeze up since the python program is essentially "frozen" when the `sleep` function is called. Working around the issue by using `pygame.time.set_timer()` to trigger a custom pygame `userevent` x milliseconds later does not work well either, since all pygame events freeze when the application window is dragged around!

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing `time.sleep(2)` with

```
for i in range(0, 200, 1):
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

This can be useful in other situations with long sleeps if you want to be able to use CTRL-C to stop the program. It also might be more convenient to use a function:

```
def MySleep(duration, resolution=10):
    """Sleep, without freezing the program. All values in ms"""
    for i in range(0, int(duration), int(resolution)):
        time.sleep(resolution / 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `pygame.time.set_timer` workaround @CodeSurgeon mentioned.

This worked for me - replacing `time.sleep(2)`, with:

```
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 2000)

should_quit = False

while not should_quit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            should_quit = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the exact same problem and found that if I moved time.sleep(2) directly after pygame.quit() it worked as intended. I'm new to pygame and not sure why this works

```
screen_text = font.render('Test', True, red)
gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, stdlib time.sleep() does not work in pygame.
However, pygame does have its own time function.
Here is the code I wrote to print out a message, character by character.

```
message = ""
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
message_text_x = 0
message_text_y = 550
message_text_speed = 35
inF = open("chapter_1.txt")
lines = inF.readlines()

def write_message(char, x, y):
    # first render the value as text so it can be drawn on the screen using screen.blit
    message_text = font.render(char, True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(message_text, (x, y))

running = True
while running:
    for line in lines:
        for char in line:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        running = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        message_text_speed = 10

            message += char
            write_message(message, message_text_x, message_text_y)
            pygame.event.pump()
            pygame.time.delay(message_text_speed)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)
```

When spacebar is clicked the speed of the text becomes faster